# I need 5v@500mA to 12v@5A for 2.5 seconds every 5 minutes

Tags: power-supply, power, boost, charging, lipo

I've run into quite the problem. I have a load that requires 12v@5A for under 2.5 seconds. However, my supply is a USB 5v@500mA. This is not an immediate load. The load will only need to be activated once per 5 minutes, so I have some time for charging of possibly capacitors or a lipo.

What would be the best way to go about this? I've could not find any boost converter for that much of a power increase, so I know I'm going to have to store that charge somehow.

I've researched adding a lipo and a charger circuit, however, I cannot seem to find a 3S lipo charger that is in a package with exposed leads. In previous exchange forums the BQ24115 was recommended, however I don't have the capability to solder that small of a device currently with my time restraints. Also, I don't see how that chip monitors 3 cells, as all the applications provided in the datasheet seem to be for only a 1 or 2 cell LiPo, which I still can't figure out how the chip balances the cells as I see no hookup for "cell 1 sense" or "cell 2 sense". There has to be an input somewhere for it to read the individual cell voltages, assuming that chip can do balance charge.

Capacitors. I don't know very much about them, however I do know it is a potential route. A colleague recommended I charge capacitors individually, then use a transistor to arrange them in series for the load dump. (because I need 12v out from the caps, with an input of 5v).

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Rather than use the difficult-to-solder chip, try looking through the selection at https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-battery-management/713

Comment: "*I've could not find any boost converter for that much of a power increase*", good, if you did find any then it would've been a scam.

Comment: What exactly is that 12V@5A load?

Comment: @HarrySvensson I have a device that requires 12v @ 5A to activate.

Comment: @jsotola Yes I actually have 500mA to spare. I understand V stands for volts, not sure where I messed that one up.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness here but if you have time constraints, a simpler technology to use/charge would be a SLA battery.  Granted it'd be bulkier/heavier but it's off the shelf for chargers, adding an overcurrent cutout should be relatively easy.

Comment: 12V@5A is 60 watts.  2.5 seconds * 60 watts is 150 Joules.  You can't easily suck a capacitor completely dry, so let's look for a cap that can hold 200J.  That works out to about 2.7 farad.  So you **could** use a honkin' big bank of 16V capacitors, charged to 12V over the course of (150J / (5V * 0.5A) = ) 60 seconds, but my oh my that'd be a large capacitor bank (just go shopping for enough 16V caps so that the sum of their capacitance is 2.7 farads).  So that's out, unless you're a happy lunatic.

Comment: So, after my own comments, I'd go with batteries.  SLA would be cheapest, LiPo may be lighter of the two, but require more care and feeding, and LiPo's tend to show their unhappiness by bursting into flame, while SLA's just die undramatic (and safe) deaths.  In any case, pay close attention to the discharge rate -- you're going to be more limited by the current the battery can deliver than by the total amount of charge it can hold.

Comment: RE "I've could not find any boost converter for that much of a power increase, "
That's not surprising because a boost converter doesn't provide any power increase at all. The product of the output voltage and current, \$V_o I_o\$, will always be less than the product of input voltage and current \$V_i I_i\$.

Comment: @TimWescott thank you! I will take a further look into seeing if I can't make that work.

Answer (score 1):

At 12v at 5 amp, for 2.5 seconds, you need to store 150 joules.

At 100 volts across a capacitor, the formula

Energy = 0.5 * C * V^2

may guide you.

A one farad cap at 100 volts holds 5,000 joules. Thus you need about 0.03 Farad cap.

Comment: And for OP's case, he'll need a 12F cap for those 12V...

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen That is assuming that he can get all the energy from the capacitor which is very unrealistic. Something more realistic would be to charge the capacitor to, say, 100 V and then use a buck converter to get it down to 12 V. In other words, \$J = \frac{C}{2}V^2 => J = \frac{C}{2}(V_{high}^2-V_{low}^2) => C = \frac{2J}{V_{high}^2-V_{low}^2} => C = 30\$ mF, assuming 100% energy conversion. - And yes, he could connect one end of the capacitors pins to the 5 V rail so the capacitor will be charged to 100-5 = 95 V which might be an easier capacitor to find.

Comment: @HarrySvensson True, but then he'd also need a boost converter for the 100V rail. The plot thickens. :-) Note that I am not saying it's impossible, just a bit more complicated than one would need (which is also not saying OP is not willing). Also, I was wrong, it's 2.something F, I mistakenly (right word?) calculated for 5V not 12V (got confused with 5A).

Comment: Yes, it's 2 something F. F that. F it. You're right.

Comment: Boosting the voltage up to 100 and then dropping it back down to 12 seems like  unnecessary power losses.

Comment: @HavocRC boosting up to 100V improves the storage efficiency of the capacitor. Note that voltage is the squared term in the capacitor energy equation. It allows you to store a larger amount of energy in a much smaller capacitor, lowering part size and cost.

Comment: @ChrisFernandez thank you man I will check it out and see if I can't make something like that work

Comment: @HavocRC well, sure. It might be unnecessary power losses. You decided to not answer my earlier question. So **we** will never know, **you** might. - also, pushing it up to 100 V and then stepping down to 12 V ensures that you will get ~12 V out. Whereas not boosting it up will always give you a voltage drop over time. At t=0 you might have 12 V available, at t=2.5 maybe you’ve discharged the capacitor to 8 volt. Whereas with the 100 V it would be maybe at 20 V and since 20>12 you can still step down to 12 V. But 8<12 V => problem...? Again, **we** don’t know because you decided to not answer.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I'm super confused what question I didn't answer I read all the comments I must be severely missing something! I understand what you are talking about with the 100v cap now, I did some research. I'm currently working on a circuit.

Comment: Anyways thank you everybody for the invaluable info!

Comment: @HavocRC "*I have a device that requires 12v @ 5A to activate.*" is not a proper answer to "*What **exactly** is that 12V@5A load?*". But anyways, good luck.

Comment: @chris Fernandez, a 150 joule capacitor will have approximately the same physical size whatever the voltage - you don't get to use a smaller "size" by using a higher voltage.

Comment: @ Jasen That makes sense. With the energy stored in the volume of the dielectric, as the polarized molecules are twisted in the Efield between the plates/foil to store the energy.

Comment: @Jasen are you sure? Picking one arbitrary example: 

For a 150 joule capacitor, you could use either 1F, 17.3V or you could use 1mF, 550V. Looking at Digikey, I'm seeing the higher voltage capacitors at about 1/2 the physical size, and 1/3 the cost: 4638PHBK-ND vs ALF20C102FP600-ND. 

Maybe there's something I'm missing? Can you elaborate on your argument that they should be the same size?

Comment: It was an approximation, increasing the voltage 30 times has led to only a 2/3 reduction in physical size.